# Error when changing column type in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, alter-table, cql3, datastax

I am having trouble changing the type of the column in a table in cassandra.

Here is the link to the [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html#cql/cql_reference/alter_table_r.html) which says that it is possible to change the type if the column is not part of the PRIMARY KEY and does not have an INDEX on it. I just can't get it to work.

```
cqlsh:test> show VERSION  
[cqlsh 3.1.8 | Cassandra 1.2.13 | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.36.2]

CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id1 text,
  id2 text,
  col1 int,
  col2 bigint,
  col3 text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id2 DESC);

UPDATE mytable SET col1 = 123, col2 = 1234, col3 = '12345' WHERE id1 = 'id1' AND id2 = 'id2';

SELECT * FROM mytable ;

 id1 | id2 | col1 | col2 | col3
-----+-----+------+------+-------
 id1 | id2 |  123 | 1234 | 12345
```

When I attempt to change column types, I get errors.

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER col1 TYPE text;
 Bad Request: Cannot change col1 from type int to type text: types are incompatible.

 ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER col1 TYPE text;
 Bad Request: Cannot change col1 from type int to type text: types are incompatible.

 ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER col2 TYPE text;
 Bad Request: Cannot change col2 from type bigint to type text: types are incompatible.

 ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER col3 TYPE bigint;
 Bad Request: Cannot change col3 from type text to type bigint: types are incompatible.

 ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER col3 TYPE int;
 Bad Request: Cannot change col3 from type text to type int: types are incompatible.
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the page you linked:

> The bytes stored in values for that column remain unchanged, and if
>   existing data cannot be [deserialized] according to the new type, your CQL
>   driver or interface might report errors

Thus, you can only change between compatible types.

This is primarily intended for people upgrading from a Thrift schema where it was common to leave all columns defined as a blob.

Comment: Thanks. So, what are the compatible types? I am confused, because I thought changing int/bigint to text should work just fine as serialization shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Ints are always 4 bytes.  Text is UTF-8, so roughly one byte per character, e.g. the string "0" is one byte and the string "100000" is 6.

Comment: I am getting the same error trying to change a type from float to decimal, is there a solution for this?